# What does [b, c][a < b < c]+'000'[a < c:] expression do?

Tags: python

This is the code about to find out dice gamble's prize amount:

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
if a == b and b == c:   #same all of dice numbers
    print(10000 + (a * 1000))
elif a == b or b == c:  #same two of dice numbers
    print(1000 + (b * 100))
elif a == c:            #same two of dice numbers
    print(1000 + (a * 100))
else:                   #no same number
    print(max(a, b, c)*100)
```

This is equivalent:

```
*_, a, b, c=sorted(input())
print(['1'+b, c][a < b < c]+'000'[a < c:])
```

---

But i can't understanding about what does
`['1'+b, c][a < b < c]`
and
`'000'[a < c:]`
do.

So, I had tried to find out the meaning of

```
`['1'+b, c][a < b < c]`
```

I found this is similar with

```
`c if a<b<c else '1'+b`
```

but i can't be sure about that.

anyway, about

```
`'000'[a < c:]`
```

I tried input `a=c` to

```
`print('000'[a < c:])`
```

It shows `000`.

I tried else that input `a<c`, it shows `00`

Anyone can tell me about this expression?

Comment: `'000'[a < c:]` === `'000'[(a < c):]` === `'000'[True:] if a < c else '000'[False:]` === `'00' if a < c else '000'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original is unnecessarily cryptic. It uses the fact that:

```
int(False) == 0
int(True)  == 1
```

For instance,

```
'000'[False:]  == '000'[0:] == '000'
'000'[True:]   == '000'[1:] == '00'
```

Similarly,

```
['1' + b, c][False] == ['1' + b, c][0] == '1' + b
['1' + b, c][True]  == ['1' + b, c][1] == c
```

---

Here's an equivalent rewrite:

```
prefix = c if a < b < c else '1' + b
suffix = '00' if a < c else '000'
print(prefix + suffix)
```

Comment: is there any advatage to use this syntax, except exhibiting the coder's excellence?

Comment: @LeiYang The biggest issue here is the implicit `bool -> int` conversion, which incidentally would make tools like mypy or pylint unhappy. In some rare cases, something similar might make sense, but only if various sub-expressions are given useful names to make it clear and understandable.

Comment: Thank you for your gentle and perfect answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The string `'000'` has length 3. The boolean `a < c` has value `False` or `True`. The operation `s[i]` for a string `s` and integer `i` refers to the `i`'th element of `s`, and the operation `s[i:]` takes the substring of `s` from index `i` through the end of `s`. A boolean value will be converted to an integer in Python as follows: `False` becomes `0` and `True` becomes `1`.

So, `'000'[a < c:]` is the same as `'000'[0:]` if `a < c` is `False`, and this is the same as `'000'`. If `a < c` is `True`, then `'000'[a < c:]` is the same as `'000'[1:]` which is `'00'`.

Answer (score 1):

`a < c` will evaluate to either `True` or `False`. So you are effectively getting either `print('000'[True:])` or `print('000'[False:])`.

When you have the `[]` after a string, those will perform a slice on the string. You'd see this in actually practice as something like the following ([here's a link for more info](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp):

```py
'abcde'[2] # returns 'c', which, starting from zero, is 2nd item
'abcde'[0] # returns 'a', which is the zero-th item
'abcde'[1:3] # returns 'bc', starting from the 1st item and going to the 3rd, not inclusive of the third
```

It looks like if you use booleans in such a slice, the `False` acts as a `0` and `True` acts as a `1`

```py
"abcde"[True] == "abcde"[1] # evaluates to true, these are the same
'abcde'[True] # evaluates to 'b'
"abcde"[False] == "abcde"[2] # evaluates to `False`
"abcde"[True] == "abcde"[2] # evaluates to `False`
"abcde"[False] == "abcde"[0] # evaluates to True, because False is effectively 0 here
```

So, having a `[True:]` or `[False:]` in that string-slice is the same as having `[1:]` or '[0:]`, which is saying to "give all characters starting with the second (for True/1:) or first (for False/0:) in this string".